# process failed with exit code 1

Tags: java, nightmare

I'm trying to run "nightmare" script, for screen shots using the following code:
"usr.dir" contain the path until the "\src\...."

```
String root = System.getProperty("usr.dir");
String screenshotJS = "node " + root + "\\src\\main\\resources\\screenshot.js";
try {

  File tempFile = File.createTempFile(root, ".png");

  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(screenshotJS + " " + url + " " + tempFile.toString());

  p.waitFor();

  int exitCode = p.exitValue();
  if (exitCode != 0) {
    System.out.println("Error Execute when exitCode=1");
  }else{
    System.out.println("Fine Execute when exitCode=0");
    }

  BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(
          500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB );
  File outputfile = new File(tempFile.getName());
  ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", outputfile);
  return tempFile.getName();
```

The nightmare script:

```
    const nightmare = require('nightmare')();
    nightmare
   .goto(process.argv[2])
   .viewport(1152, 864)
   .screenshot(process.argv[3] || 'screenshot.png')
   .end(() => {});
```

The return value of the process is 1.
What I'm doing wrong ? can someone please assist me with this case?

Thanks,

Ido

Comment: Can you paste the error or logs any?

Comment: Error Execute when exitCode=1

Comment: There are a lot of things that can be wrong here.  Most obviously, your screenshot.js script could be failing.  You haven't shown us that script, so how can we know?  Also, you pass in 'url' as a parameter to that script, but don't show us what the value of 'url' is.  There may be nothing wrong with the code you're showing us.  [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @IdoSegal  this is error code which is not sufficient to trace exact error. I will suggest use some logging framework

Comment: Hi I've added the script

Comment: Blindly passing a constructed string to exec is almost guaranteed to return non-zero. Since this String is dependent on other Strings we don't see, you need to make sure that whatever it is you are doing works outside of Java. Perhaps as a command line or something. Not to mention that you aren't actually reporting the actual exit code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolved after I've ran `npm i nightmare`